# SSRS Data Source Connection Issue?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssrs-2008

I deploy a report solution from Visual Studio report builder and upload several reports onto SSRS.

I try my connection but failed and other previous reports which used different connection setting worked.

Please see below the two connection settings: The first figure is mine and the second figure is others'. The only difference is the 'Data Source' in 'Connection String'. Can you please advice why this cause the problem and how I can fix it? If I use 'localhost' to create my data source in my local desktop, the report cannot be compiled successfully.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by the following tricks:

1. When you first time deploy the solution, you should set the properties properly, like figures showing. Normally, I only configured 'Debug' because I use a single server for both data source and report delivery.
2. Set TargetServerURL with the client end IP address unless you are on the server itself which can be 'localhost'. This would make sure you deliver the reports to the right remote server withour error.
3. Login the SSRS and check the data source loaded. Normally, SSRS would automatically change the IP address into 'localhost' which is good to go for report viewing. If it still was the IP address as what I described in the question, you can try to go back to the Visual Studio report builder and change the IP address into 'localhost'. Then, don't preview the report but directly deploy the solution which ensure the new data source takes 'localhost' in SSRS. For the report was ever deployed to a specified server, so 'localhost' would not make any ambiguousness and the deployment can still locate the same server to renew the stuffs in SSRS.  A key thing here is to reset the 'OverwriteDataSource' into 'True'.

Hope this help. Cheers

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue seams with user RepoerReader.

At your local database you have crated user RepoerReader

But  your remote database located 10.12.13.14 database you you do not have user RepoerReader and are you sure and make sure port is correct or your password is wrong.

Comment: Previous reports were created in the remote machine 10.12.13.14 so they can be based on localhost. The port and pw were correct by test.

Comment: Ping the matching.. and check database is running on matching and there are no firewall set by network team..

Comment: did this got solved... if not can you open trace on server and check.